# Why the keyup or keypress events doesn't enable the commandButton

Tags: primefaces

**CASE 1:**

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateSaveButton" process="@this" update="saveCB" />
<p:inputText onkeyup="updateSaveButton();" required="true" value="#{invoiceBB.company}"/>
<p:commandButton action="#{invoiceBB.save}" disabled="#{invoiceBB.company == null}" id="saveCB" value="Open dialog x" />
```

**CASE 2:**

```
<p:inputText required="true" value="#{invoiceBB.company}">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" update="saveCB" />
</p:inputText>
<p:commandButton action="#{invoiceBB.save}" disabled="#{invoiceBB.company == null}" id="saveCB" value="Open dialog x" />
```

If I see the backing bean, the value of company is null. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer your second approach, example:

```
    <h:form>
        <p:message id="messagecompany" for="inputcompany"/>
        <p:inputText id="inputcompany" required="true" value="#{testBean.company}">
            <p:ajax event="keyup" update="saveCB messagecompany" />
        </p:inputText>
        <p:commandButton id="saveCB"
            action="#{testBean.save}"
            disabled="#{testBean.company eq null or facesContext.validationFailed}"
            value="Open dialog x" />
    </h:form>
```